How to prove a Sobolev inequality involving norms with these parameters?
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold of diemnsion $N$, $H^1(M)$ and $L^q(M)$ being respectively the Sobolev space and Lebesgue space, where $q\in[2, \frac{2n}{n-2}),$ but with the different respective norms $\|u\|_{\varepsilon}^2:=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^N}\left(\varepsilon^2 \int_M\left|\nabla_g\right|^2 d \mu_g+\int_M u^2 d \mu_g\right)$ and $|u|_{q, \varepsilon}:=\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon^N} \int_M|u|^q d \mu_g\right)^{1 / q},$
where $\varepsilon$ is a positive parameter (which can be arbitarily small). How can one prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ not depending on $\varepsilon$ such that
$$
|u|_{q, \varepsilon} \leq c\|u\|_{\varepsilon}.
$$
PS: Using the classic Sobolev embedding, I could get a constant that could get arbitrarily large when $\varepsilon$ is small. However, I need one which doesn't depend on $\varepsilon.$

Is your manifold compact?

Yes, it is compact!

For the ones who are reading my question, I appreciate it, but I have solved it already. There it goes the proof:
Since the manifold is compact, you can cover it with a finite number of balls. So you use the classic Sobolev inequality in a ball and substitute $u(x)$ by $u(\varepsilon x).$ The desired inequality follows immediately.
